# Comparing two rows from the same table

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two rows from the same table and I want to get the column names with different values for these rows.

I know I can get this with a simple `for` loop like the example below, but perhaps django already has a method to get this done.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
#---
a = MyModel(name='A', email='a@z.com')
a.save()
b = MyModel(name='B', email='b@z.com')
b.save()
#---
recA = MyModel.object.get(pk=1)
recB = MyModel.object.get(pk=2)
#---
diff = []
colNames = [
    'email', 
    'name', 
]
for a in colNames:
    if getattr(recA, a) == getattr(recB, a):
        pass
    else:
        diff.append(a)
```

Comment: Can you please share some codes on how you want to compare?

Comment: @ruddra. Example added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows with atleast one column having different values, you can query like this:

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2]).distinct().values('email','name')
```

[distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will eliminate the duplicate rows from query results.

Comment: This will not tell me if the values for email and/or name are different in the two rows. If result is not empty I only know that at least one column is different but I do not know which one.

Comment: Then you can just chain the distinct() function after values() like this:                   
result = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2]).values('email','name').distinct()

Comment: Nope. This return the entire row for MyModel.id = 2